# How do I preload or install static files into Highchart's export server?

Tags: node.js, highcharts, phantomjs

This is so if I export a chart using HTML, I can reference styling classes and so my chart will generate as it is on my web application.

Currently I tried storing the CSS in my resources.json file however, the styling does not seem to be applying to any of my charts.

I know in line styling tags apply to the chart when I use it in my HTML however, since I have a lot of styling it is preferable to load it all on once using resources.json

### Update

The command d_paul provided works, and so thank you for that!

I was trying to load up the resources with the `enableServer` command but it wouldn't read it.

Is there anyway to send in the `resources` argument through the exporting API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting

I know you can send JSON to the server with the resources argument and have it render that way, just wondering if there is a way to send it through the exporting API i linked above.

Or if not through the API, if I can load up the resources when I start the server using the enableServer argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a simple `resources.json` file in node-export-server folder which looks like this:

```
{
    "css": ".highcharts-background {fill: #bada55;}"
}
```

Generated image with this command:

`highcharts-export-server -infile chartOptions.json -outfile chart.png`

And the CSS style applied without any problems. Tested on the newest version of Node Export Server (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server).

Comment: Thank you! I am still trying to figure out a way to send it in using the enableServer argument so I can send resources through the highcharts exporting API (if that is even possible). I updated my question above!